# I would like to know about the composition of a compressed air system

Tags: compressed-air

I am a graduate student and I am planning to conduct high-speed flow experiments using a high-pressure tank. The equipment we currently have is a compressor, air tank, and regulator, and the regulator consists of two stages. The tank is charged to 100 bar, and the pressure is lowered to 50 bar in the first stage regulator and lowered to about 3 bar in the second stage regulator. The flow rate required in the test section is about 1.9 kg per second, but as far as I know, if you just spray the tank, it will choke somewhere and the flow rate will be determined. I know that MFC is used to prevent this phenomenon and to determine and control the flow rate in the system. What I am curious about is whether it can be used together with a regulator when installing an MFC, and what order should be used to install the regulator and MFC.

Also, in this case, when the pressure of the compression tank charged to 100 bar reaches the inlet pressure of the first stage regulator, the flow rate will not be output. Is there a way to predict how long it will take for this to happen? Calculate the amount of air (kg) in the tank using the density at 100 bar, calculate the amount of air (kg) assuming the 1st stage regulator inlet pressure is 50 bar, and obtain the difference between the two air masses. Is it ok to say that the experiment can be continued by the time which is divided by the flow rate used in the test section?

Throat diameter of my test section is 2 inch at the inlet of the test chamber.

Comment: you're missing something here.  Filters aren't used to determine flow rates.  The flow rate is based on the system, and I promise that a large enough pipe will pass all the air you want.